# Using r and ggplot How do I specify specific hexadecimal color/colour values to use to represent different character values

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, hex

Assuming `is.character(MyColours) = TRUE` where MyColours contains a number of hexadecimal colour values.

How do I ensure that when I want to plot using ggplot I can ensure that MyColours[1] will always be used to represent "Ford" and MyColour[3] will represent "Toyota" when I can't guarantee the order "Ford" or "Toyota" will appear in the observations I use to plot.

While the geo_bar example below was helpful and did remind me to add column names to `MyColours` I'm hoping to plot lines not bars

```
    ggplot(MyData, aes(x = TimePeriod, y = CountOfItems, 
group = Account, color = scale_fill_manual(values = MyColours))) 
    + geom_line(size = 1) 
    + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

I get the error `Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:scale_fill_manual(values = MyColours)` even when `length(MyColours)` is equal to `length(unique(MyData$Account))`

**Sample Data**

```
dput(MyData)
structure(list(Account = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Toyota Corolla"), class = "factor"), CountOfItems = c(14, 120, 
23, 345), TimePeriod = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("2010-12", 
"2011-01", "2011-02"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Account", 
"CountOfItems", "TimePeriod"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is it possible to use scale_fill_manual with line plots?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example when asking R questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5):

You could name `MyColours`, e.g. like this:

```
MyColour <- c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF") 
names(MyColour) <- c("Mazda RX4", "Toyota Corolla", "Fiat 128")

df <- mtcars[c("Mazda RX4", "Toyota Corolla", "Fiat 128"), ]
df$car <- rownames(df)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = car, y = mpg, fill = car)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = MyColour)
```

Comment: Edit your post and add a reproducible example.

Comment: Updated question but still learning R and stackoverflow so apologies for forgetting the markdown.

Comment: No problem. I guess everyone went through that learning process here. When I run your code, I get - amongst other errors - `Error in ggplot(MyData, aes(x = TimePeriod, y = CountOfItems, group = Account,  :  object 'MyData' not found`. Please add it - or a similar data set. The link that I provided shows how.

Comment: Sample data added where I want to color the lines in the plot of the data accounting to the `MyColour` so Mazda RX4 would use #FF0000 for its line colour

Comment: Try `ggplot(MyData, aes(x = TimePeriod, y = CountOfItems, group = Account, color = Account)) + geom_line(size = 1) + scale_color_manual(values = MyColours) `

Comment: That worked. Thanks @lukA. If I'm honest I'm not sure why though